# How to compile CSS into SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I use SASS to write my CSS but it is not a standard where I work. If another developer works on CSS, they work directly on the .css file. Is there anyway to compile CSS into SCSS output?

Comment: Google "css to sass"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://sebastianpontow.de/css2compass/

A while ago I used it to translate a css file into scss and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

All CSS is valid SCSS. You don't need to compile it to SCSS in order to use it with an SCSS file